# Facebook Fan Page API /home

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-page

I am trying to get get the **/home** endpoint for a fan page using the Facebook API, but it returns this error:

```
Array
(
    [message] => You can only access the "home" connection for the current user.
    [type] => GraphMethodException
    [code] => 100
)
```

I tried using:

- The AuthToken of the page that I get from Facebook API using **/accounts**
- The AuthToken of the parent account that has rights to that page

None of them work, returning the same error every time.

NOTE: it works fine if I try to get the **/home** of the parent account and using its AuthToken.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the

```
GET /{page_id}/feed
```

endpoint (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page/feed/).

There's no `/{page_id}/home` for pages, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page/#edges